# Image zoom in and zoom out in ionic slider

Tags: ionic-framework, slider, zooming

I am developing an ionic 3 android application and for a requirement uses ionic slide like

`ion-slide` tag with  `zoom="true"`

I need to zoom in and zoom out the images in the slide on clicking an icon.

Is there any way to zoom in and zoom out this section dynamically?